# Problem with deserialization from object file to field

Tags: java, serialization

my problems is that I don't really know why the object is not saving in the field of my class, I'm doing some small star management program for Semestral project for Programming in Java. So my question is why when object deserialize correctly but don't save in the field. Is there a possibility that the fields in the object file are empty?

```
private void setConstellation(Constellation constellation) {
        Object obj;
        File constellationFile = new File("src\\Constellations\\" + constellation.getNazwa() + ".obj");
        boolean constellationExist = constellationFile.exists();

        if(constellationExist == true) {
            try {
                ObjectInputStream loadStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("src\\Constellations\\" + constellation.getNazwa() + ".obj"));
                while ((obj = loadStream.readObject()) != null) {
                    if (obj instanceof Constellation && ((Constellation) obj).getNazwa().equals(constellation.getNazwa())) {
                        this.constellation = constellation;
                    }
                }
            } catch (EOFException ex) {
                System.out.println("End of file");
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(constellationExist == false){
            try{
                ObjectOutputStream saveStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("src\\Constellations\\" + constellation.getNazwa() + ".obj"));
                saveStream.writeObject(constellation);
                this.constellation = constellation;
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

While debugging this part of program, the while loop in first if don't event check :/
Can you help me somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `saveStream.close()` after writing the object to ensure that the stream is properly flushed.

You should also close the `loadStream`.

If you're on Java 7 or newer, you can use try-with-resources:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream saveStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream("src\\Constellations\\" + 
                             constellation.getNazwa() + ".obj"))) {
    saveStream.writeObject(constellation);
    this.constellation = constellation;
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This construct ensures that the stream is closed when you exit the `try` block.

Comment: Yeah then I saw that and facepalm myself, but thanks :)